# Google Assistant Smart Home : Is Google smart home support custom command for water Heater devices?

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I have a number of devices. I want to control it through google smart home. Is it possible to create **custom commands** ? I want to develop commands like "I want to take a shower".
can I custom the trait? Thank you. Is there any support for circulation action?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create custom commands ?

Here is an alternative way that allows you to use custom commands to control your device, please see [Set up and manage Routines](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7029585?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid).

If you’d like to use “*I want to take a shower*” command to open your water heater, please follow suggestions below

- Choosing **Voice command** to trigger the Routine when you add a Starter

  [image: Add a voice command starter]

  [image: Input a utterance]
- Choosing **Custom command** when you set an Action on the app

  [image: Set a custom command action]

  [image: Input a custom command]
- Test the command through Google Assistant app

  [image: Test the command through Google Assistant app]

Comment: Christina P. Hi, I  want to support at the skills level. not user level can developer develop the or able to support custom commands i.e. I want to take a shower, I need hot water, To get my bath ready, etc.